# How can I calculate whether I can form a group of 10 tournament matches from a limited set of matches/pairs?

Tags: combinations

I'm trying to work out whether I can form 10 matches from a set of 98 possible player pairings (which includes 20 individuals).

Each player must play in one, and only one, of the matches.

A computational approach is fine, but there are too many possibilities to enumerate---14005614014756, to be precise, i.e. choose(98, 10).

The data for the allowable match pairs is:

`Player01    Player13
Player01    Player14
Player02    Player03
Player02    Player04
Player02    Player05
Player02    Player06
Player02    Player07
Player02    Player08
Player02    Player09
Player02    Player10
Player02    Player11
Player02    Player12
Player02    Player13
Player02    Player14
Player02    Player15
Player02    Player16
Player02    Player17
Player02    Player18
Player02    Player19
Player02    Player20
Player03    Player04
Player03    Player05
Player03    Player06
Player03    Player07
Player03    Player08
Player03    Player09
Player03    Player10
Player03    Player11
Player03    Player12
Player03    Player13
Player03    Player14
Player03    Player15
Player03    Player16
Player03    Player17
Player03    Player18
Player03    Player19
Player03    Player20
Player04    Player05
Player04    Player06
Player04    Player07
Player04    Player08
Player04    Player09
Player04    Player10
Player04    Player11
Player04    Player12
Player04    Player13
Player04    Player14
Player04    Player15
Player04    Player16
Player04    Player17
Player04    Player18
Player04    Player19
Player04    Player20
Player06    Player07
Player06    Player08
Player06    Player09
Player06    Player10
Player06    Player11
Player06    Player12
Player06    Player13
Player06    Player14
Player06    Player15
Player06    Player16
Player06    Player17
Player06    Player18
Player06    Player19
Player06    Player20
Player07    Player09
Player07    Player15
Player08    Player09
Player08    Player10
Player08    Player11
Player08    Player12
Player08    Player13
Player08    Player14
Player08    Player15
Player08    Player16
Player08    Player17
Player08    Player18
Player08    Player19
Player08    Player20
Player09    Player10
Player09    Player13
Player09    Player14
Player09    Player15
Player09    Player20
Player10    Player13
Player13    Player14
Player13    Player15
Player13    Player17
Player14    Player20
Player16    Player17
Player16    Player18
Player16    Player19
Player16    Player20
Player18    Player19
Player18    Player20
Player19    Player20`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify the existence of one using the [blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm).